# Oracle: ORA-00932 when converting column_expression from user_ind_expressions using to_lob

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, ora-00932

Try running these two simple statements on Oracle 10.2:

```
CREATE TABLE mytest
   (table_name varchar2(30), 
   index_name varchar2(30), 
   column_expression clob,
   column_position number);

INSERT INTO mytest 
  (table_name,
   index_name,
   column_expression, 
   column_position) 
SELECT table_name, index_name,
       to_lob(column_expression), column_position 
FROM user_ind_expressions EXPRA 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 FROM user_constraints 
    WHERE constraint_name = EXPRA.index_name 
    AND table_name = EXPRA.table_name);
```

This results in this error:

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG

If I omit the WHERE NOT EXISTS like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytest 
   (table_name,index_name,column_expression, column_position) 
SELECT table_name,index_name,
       to_lob(column_expression), column_position 
FROM user_ind_expressions EXPRA;
```

It works:

23 rows created.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

If Michel Cadot [says](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/125912/352199/0/) its a bug, then its almost certainly a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, seems like it.

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/m/352199/130782/#msg_352199